# Tikz overlaying picture with \newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am trying to use \newcommand to reproduce a tikz diagram multiple times. When i make these diagrams manually, they are drawn appropriate, but when i reproduce them with \newcommand, they slightly go to right side. I have tried removing space by using \% at the end of tikzpicture, but that is not working for me. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=5cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\newcommand{\tklines}[1]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[red,overlay]
\draw (0,#1)--++(5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw (0,0)--++(5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw (0,1)--++(5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw (0,2)--++(5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{5cm}
\tklines{0}
\tklines{1}
\tklines{2}
\end{document}
```

The result is displayed in following picture. See red lines going to right side. I have tried to search several time but I think i am missing something. Kindly help. 
[image]

Comment: you have `{ ` so put a space before each tikzpicture, use `{%`

Comment: I have put a the percentage sign just after the curly brackets i.e. the curly brackets of the `\newcommand` third argument, but it does not solve the problem - lines are still going to the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Carlisle said, only a few `%` are missing,
one in the command definition, before the `\begin{tikzpicture}`, and one after each call of `\tklines{X}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=5cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\newcommand{\tklines}[1]{% <-[ HERE ]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[red,overlay]
    \draw (0,#1)--++(5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \draw (0,0)--++(5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \draw (0,1)--++(5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \draw (0,2)--++(5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\hspace{5cm}
%
\tklines{0}% <-[ HERE ]
\tklines{1}% <-[ HERE ]
\tklines{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that when i have already put '% in the new command why should it be put <-[Here]. It is working.